# How to fix "NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'path' was called on null" on ImagePicker Cancel Button?

Tags: flutter

Guys I am using `ImagePicker` plugin to access the images in my app, but if I decide to cancel it I get this error `NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'path' was called on null`. Any idea on How to fix it?

here is my `ImagePicker`:

```
FlatButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            final PickedFile file =
                await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
            editImage(file.path);
          },
          child: Text('Câmera'),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with:

```
FlatButton(
          onPressed: () async {
            final PickedFile file =
                await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
            if (file != null) {
              editImage(file.path);
            }
          },
          child: Text('Câmera'),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
editImage(file?.path?"");
```